# How to pass selected record Ids from list view to flow URL?

Tags: visual-workflow, custom-button, list-view

I have the below List Button URL configured in the Account object.

```
https://myDomain.lightning.force.com/flow/Delete_Records?ListOfIds={!Account.Id}
```

When I click the button in list view, it should grab all the selected Ids and delete the records.

[image]

When I run the flow via button, I am getting the below error.

[image]

When I hardcode the Id and test it in the list button URL it works fine. So I am not sure where I am going wrong.

Comment: Check out [this](https://wiki.sfxd.org/books/cool-links-stuff/page/how-to-check-off-records-on-a-list-view-and-pass-them-all-to-a-flow-%28button%29) similar implementation done around this scenario.

Comment: also [documented by Matt and Neil](https://www.xbaf.com/flow-list-buttons)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I figured out the issue. In the button URL I don’t need to pass any flow parameters. In the flow, I should have a collection variable called ids. You cannot use any other name other than ids.

Please refer to my blog for complete solution: https://sfdxtips.wordpress.com/2021/06/17/salesforce-tips-19-mass-delete-records-from-list-view-using-flow-2/

Comment: Hey Krishnamurthy, could you please show how you solved this issue? How does the flow receive the ids from the list view?

Comment: @jdrees I have updated the answer. Please refer to the blog.