# Edit Event list view layout

Tags: list-view, quickaction

I have created a mass update action of the Event Status field which I now want to add to the list view layout for the Events. The problem is that the layout doesn't exist under Object Manager - Events - List View Button Layout. And there is also no option to create a new list view layout.

Since Event list views are a part of the Calendar tab I was hoping to find the layout there but Calendar doesn't exist as a separate object.
There is also a list view layout for the Activity object (which in the end includes Event records), however there is no option to create actions, only buttons or links.

So far I wasn't able to find any documentation covering specifically layouts for the object Events.

If editing the list view layout for Events is not an option, I would be grateful for any hints on a mass update possibility of the Event Status field anywhere else (inline editing is disabled for in my company).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:-

[image]

you need to add on activity list view layout

[image]

i created list button on event object

[image]

### UPDATE

You need to use flow and get the selected record id from list view inside flow and perform mass action, check out this:- [How to pass selected record Ids from list view to flow URL?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/347036/how-to-pass-selected-record-ids-from-list-view-to-flow-url)

Simplly call the flow url in list button and it should give you the mass action functionality.

Comment: Thanks  but I need this to be an action that would mass update the status of multiple events. I don't think a button could do that.

Comment: @MarkB read my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

The problem here isn't getting the button into the list, it's selecting multiple events. Filtering to the record type is not exposing the ability to select multiple events to pass their ids into a flow.

I'm going to end up creating an app page and doing the whole thing in flow with the USF Datatable component.